# statsmodels adfuller for strong stationarity

Tags: statsmodels

I'm using adfuller to identify if the output of an stochastic simulation reached an equilibrium. I thought that the Augmented Dickey Fuller test would achieve this task but it is finding stationarity where the values are still not stable. For example, in this image the values are clearly decreasing:

[time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNpfw.png)

But running this:

```
results = = adfuller(values, regression="c")
```

I got this outcome:

- p-value: 8.73279419229e-06
- adf: -5.20143922846 with 1% of -3.46469407554

How is the null hypothesis of a unit root rejected? I thought that if I specify that the regression has only a constant then time series with trends are not identified as stationary. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `regression="nc"`. AFAICS, the trend/regression term is added to the regression for the differenced series, i.e. a constant means there is drift. Your series looks approximately stationary after differencing with nonzero mean. The docstring might be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Aside to the problem: If you want to test whether the series has approximately settled to a constant, then I would do a windowed trend test which most likely has more power than ADF.

Comment: I see your point about the trend test...I misunderstood that constant means that the drift is constant (somehow I assumed that it means that the mean was constant). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your P-value is too small, usually we reject the null hypothesis when p-value < 0.05 for a 0.95% confidence interval